# Python: space in multiple-line format output

Tags: python, pep8

Trying to re-factor codes by pep8.

Codes:

```
    print """Exception when sending email to: {0},
        from: {1}, subject: {2}, e: {3}""".format(to, fr, subject, e)
```

Output:

```
Exception when sending email to: to,
                from: fr, subject: subject, e: Invalid URL 'http//127.0.0.1:8000/'
```

How to remove the space before `from` in above output? Thanks

**UPDATE**

The following codes working fine. Should I delete this post?

```
 34             print ($
 35                 "Exception when sending email to: {0},"$
 36                 "from: {1}, subject: {2}, e: {3}").format(to, fr, subject, e)$
```

Comment: String literals don't need to be indented in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `"""`, you should search for the term *"triple-quotes"* at [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

**Change:**

```
print """Exception when sending email to: {0},
        from: {1}, subject: {2}, e: {3}""".format(to, fr, subject, e)
```

**To:**

```
print """Exception when sending email to: {0}, from: {1}, subject: {2}, e: {3}""".format(to, fr, subject, e)
```

**Edit:**

If you need to keep your lines short, you can also use `\` to continue the multi-line statement:

**Code:**

```
print("""Exception when sending email \
to: {0}, \
from: {1}, \
subject: {2}, \
e: {3}""".format('to', 'fr', 'subject', 'e'))
```

**Output:**

```
Exception when sending email to: to, from: fr, subject: subject, e: e
```

Comment: I need to keep each line containing less than 79 chars.

Comment: Updated my answer... take a look.